# How to load custom dll in R

Tags: r, dll

When running a R script in a windows console using a custom DLL
, I get the error "can't load shared object path\dllname".

But the DLL is exactly in this location.
Further, using the R gui, I can execute the script.

Where is R looking for DLLs ?

My call is:

```
dyn.load(paste("myrdll", .Platform$dynlib.ext, sep=""))
```

The DLL is located in the same folder as the script and in addition in
the appropriate system folder.
What is R expecting in addition?

Thank you

Comment: getwd() returns the same folder and dyn.load("path_and_myrdll.dll") causes same error.

Comment: Does the error contain other information?  For example `LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.` or `LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: Yes. Not a valid win32 app.

Answer (score 0):

R cannot load arbitrary DLLs.  It can only load those created by compiling and linking the source files using `R CMD SHLIB`.  See the `?utils::SHLIB` help page.

Comment: The DLL wrapps another DLL and was created with SWIG. So there is also a mydll.r file. This mydll.r and mydll.dll are both in the folder with the sample script. As i mentioned, executing the script in rgui, work perfectly. The DLL is loaded and all functions executed correctly. It just not works, when executing the script with rscript myscript, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to confuse the forum: I was trying to load a 32 bit R Wrapper DLL in a 64 bit console. I was thinking the default CMD window on Win 10 64 bit is still 32 bit.  So the problem is caused by architecture mismatch.